# How do you add a navigation bar on the same line as a header?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am new to css so I thought I'd try to make a website with a navbar. I want to put my navigation bar on the same line as the header(logo). I have been trying to use float left and right to position the header and navbar on the same line but the navbar text never centers with the header.

I have tried to adjust the margin and padding to no avail. As well, tried to move the container class around. I inspected my website using the chrome dev tools and found  is contained in a  which doesn't show up in my text editor.   P.s. I changed the links to #

```css
body{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#00f;
  font-family:"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin:0;
}

 .container{
   width:80%;
   margin: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

.clr{
  clear:none;
}

 #logo{
   border:3px solid #00f;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   float:left
 }

 #navbar{
   margin:0;
   float:right;
 }

 #navbar ul{
   padding:0;
   list-style:none;
 }

 #navbar li{
   display:inline-block;
 }

 #navbar a{
   color:#00f;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-size:18px;
   padding-right:15px;
 }
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="main-header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 id="logo">HM<h1>

        <nav id="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="clr"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox

add this style to your style

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;  
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#00f;
  font-family:"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center; 
}
#logo{
  border:3px solid;
  padding:0 10px;
}
#navbar li{
  display:inline-block;
}
#navbar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-right:15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="logo">HM</h1>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0` to `#nav-bar ul`, and the issue will be solved.